# Open external URL in same window using hyperlink formula in Salesforce Community

Tags: salesforce, formula, salesforce-communities

I have a custom formula field **Client name** and I am using the below sample formula to navigate to the external URL in the community.

```
HYPERLINK('http://salesforce.com', 'Salesforce', '_self')
```

It is opening in a new window instead of the current one, but I want it to open in the same window.

I tried `_top` and `_parent` as well, but it didn't work for me. In internal salesforce, it is working as expected.

```
IF(
AND(ISPICKVAL( Enrollment_Method__c , 'Online Enrollment'), 
NOT(Plan_Selection_Complete__c), 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c , 'Not Submitted') 
),
HYPERLINK("https://planconfirmationdev.benefitmall.com/planConfirmation/640338/0",Client_Link__c,"_self"),
IF(
AND(ISPICKVAL( Enrollment_Method__c , 'Online Enrollment'),
Plan_Selection_Complete__c,
ISPICKVAL(Status__c , 'Not Submitted')
),
HYPERLINK("https://bmall-enrollments.azurewebsites.net//canvas/ExternalLogin?enrollment_Id="+Id,Client_Link__c, "_self"),
IF(
OR(ISPICKVAL( Enrollment_Method__c , 'Manual Enrollment'),
ISPICKVAL(Status__c , 'Not Submitted') 
),
HYPERLINK("/s/enrollment/"+ Id+"/"+Name,Client_Link__c ),
HYPERLINK("/s/enrollment/"+ Id+"/"+Name,Client_Link__c )
)))
```

Comment: Are you seeing target="_self" in developer console ? Inspecting custom field with hyperlink should show - <a href="http://salesforce.com" target="_self">Salesforce</a>

Comment: @NagaSaiA yes, I am able to see it.

Comment: But still it is not working

Comment: I think there seems to be issue related to external URL, refer this links - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eM1JQAU   and did you try using window.location.as in link - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005QXgQAM

Comment: Not able to save with window.location.as or window.location.replace.

Comment: Could you please share the code with window.location which you have tried

Comment: I have added, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Salesforce regarding the above issue. We need to activate a critical update to use Hyperlinks at the lightning platform.

Go to `Setup >> Critical Update >> Lightning Experience Honors Target Values for Hyperlinks in Formula Fields >> Activate.`